# Simple 3D modeling program to simulate pipe intersections

Tags: 3d, modeling

I am looking for a software that can simulate pipe to pipe connections and if possible export a unfold from that connection.

I have to make a pipe welded into another pipe, this can be eccentric, sloped or both. The both pipe diameters can vary. Ideal solution would be parametric design or maybe powered by custom coding?

Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say if you require free software or are willing to pay. One suggestion for a free solution is [Onshape](https://www.onshape.com). This is real 3-D solid modeling that runs in the browser. It does boolean operations (which will be helpful to model the intersections between pipes) and does parametric design. It works really well. I will caution that the free license stores models publicly so it might not be suitable for businesses.

Another option is [Autodesk Fusion 360](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/overview?mktvar002=724861&mkwid=sOICwxb1H%7Cpcrid%7C226118724187%7Cpkw%7Cautodesk%20fusion%20360%7Cpmt%7Ce%7Cpdv%7Cc%7Cslid%7C%7Cpgrid%7C52893102612%7Cptaid%7Ckwd-488376946792%7C&intent=US-Fusion360-BR&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=GGL_FUSION360_US_BR_SEM_EXACT%3EBrand&utm_term=autodesk%20fusion%20360&utm_content=sOICwxb1H%7Cpcrid%7C226118724187%7Cpkw%7Cautodesk%20fusion%20360%7Cpmt%7Ce%7Cpdv%7Cc%7Cslid%7C%7Cpgrid%7C52893102612%7Cptaid%7Ckwd-488376946792%7C&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIwZW5wIvg2wIVBSlpCh1CpAxKEAAYASAAEgLsBPD_BwE). They have a free license for [students and small business](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/fusion-360/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-activate-start-up-or-educational-licensing-for-Fusion-360.html) with less than $100,000 in yearly revenue. It is more robust than Onshape in that it does both solid modeling and surfacing.

Both options have extensive training resources with on-line manuals, videos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest [Solid Edge](https://solidedge.siemens.com/en/) from Siemens. You can use their pipe routing that will automatically create pipe fittings in the intersections, or their magic pipe tool that will allow you to bend pipes and will create weldings on the intersections.

You can get a free trial for Solid Edge from their website, so you can deside before purchase. There is also a free version for students. You need to contact sales to get the paid version.

---

Do not confuse Solid Edge with [SolidWorks](https://www.solidworks.com/), which I will also suggest. The means to do pipe to pipe welding seems to be more involved in SolidWorks.

See the video [SolidWorks Tutorial #1: BMX Bicycle Frame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuHgCQgqGig) from [SolidWorks and CAD Tutor, Azeez Salu](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC06rfE9A41yYcClKJfKUKcQ) that demostrate all your requirements.

SolidWorks is a paid product, the purchase method requires to contact sales, even for a demo.

Comment: You might want to mention that neither program is “simple” rather they are industrial strength CAD packages and priced that way.